# How can I run a function or macro across a folder of files?

Tags: macro, multiple-files

Let's say I have a function, named `StripWhitespace`.

I can run it on a single file by opening the file and running `:StripWhitespace`.

How can I automatically run that function against a folder of files, and save the results as I go along?

Comment: Details, please!

Comment: See also: [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `-c` argument to run a command on startup, from `vim(1)`:

```
   -c {command}
               {command} will be executed after the first  file  has  been
               read.   {command}  is interpreted as an Ex command.  If the
               {command} contains spaces it must  be  enclosed  in  double
               quotes  (this depends on the shell that is used).  Example:
               Vim "+set si" main.c
               Note: You can use up to 10 "+" or "-c" commands.
```

Example:

```
vim -c ':call StripWhitespace()' file1 file2
```

To quit afterwards, add `| :wqa`:

```
vim -c ':call StripWhitespace() | :wqa' file1 file2
```

Comment: You want an :argdo, if you run this for a couple of files on the commandline

Answer (score 24):

If you are already in Vim, you can use the `:argdo` or `:bufdo` commands to execute a command on every item in the argument list or buffer list, respectively.

e.g. to run a `:` command on every file in the argument list:

```
:argdo StripWhitespace
```

Or to invoke a function from every file in the buffer list:

```
:bufdo call StripWhitespace()
```

Or to run macro `q` on every file in the arguments list:

```
:argdo normal @q
```

You can then save all changed buffers with `:wall`, or save all and quit Vim with `:wqall`.

If you want to write the files as you go along, you can add in a call to `:update`, like so:

```
:argdo s/foo/bar/ge | update
```

There are various ways you can get the files into Vim in the first place, including:

- Supply parameters to the vim command line: `vim *` (this adds all the files to the argument list),
- Use the `:args` command (which supports wildcards and backtick expressions) to populate the argument list, or the `:argadd` command to add files to it,
- Just open them all manually with `:e`, `:Ex`, or a file-opening plugin.

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't require leaving Vim, which in my opinion is too expensive (my precious buffer list!). I have some notes: (1) leaving buffers without writing requires `'hidden'` to be set; (2) the `: update` command is a slight improvement over `:w` because it only writes if a change has been made, so `:bufdo update` or `:argdo update` will write all modified buffers or arguments.

Comment: Good point on `update`. I considered mentioning `hidden` when I was writing the answer, but decided against it because I didn't want to overcomplicate it. On reflection though, it should be in there. I'll update the answer to include both suggestions presently.

Comment: @tommcdo Just checked the documentation for :wall, and it only writes changed buffers, so :bufdo update is not necessary after all.

Comment: good catch regarding `:wall`, which also has the advantage of not cycling through buffers and moving you away from where you started. I suppose `:argdo update` is still a different story -- maybe you don't want to write to buffers that are not in your argument list.

Comment: @tommcdo Good point.

Comment: Would be great to add `silent!` at the beginning for sake of speed!