# How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?

Tags: command-line, substitute, ex-mode, invocation

I would like to edit files passed in pipeline input using vim in non-interactive way or edit files in-place (similar to `sed`).

Few examples using `sed`:

```
$ sed -i'.bak' s/foo/test/g file   # Edit file in-place.
$ cat file | sed s/foo/test/g      # Parse file in pipeline.
```

However I could read in [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021#Using_nonstandard_tools), that:

> `sed` is a **S**tream **ED**itor, not a file editor. Nevertheless, people everywhere tend to abuse it for trying to edit files. It doesn't edit files.

Secondly some options such as in-place editing (`-i`) is portable.

How the same functionality can be achieved in vim?

Comment: I think you can drop the second `file` from your second commandline.

Comment: @joeytwiddle Done.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To edit file non-interactively using `ex` (`vi` is the visual mode for `ex`), you can use `+{command}` or `-c {command}` parameters which allows you to execute the vi commands after the first file has been read.

The `ex` is a standard command-line editor (similar to `ed`).

There is also [`vipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vipe) (a Vim command pipe editor) should be used which is part of `moreutils` package and it will allows you to run your editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and edit the data that is being piped between programs.

#### Examples

Simple standard input and output using pipes can be achieved by this shell syntax:

```
$ ex -sc'%p|q!' <(echo Example)
$ echo Example | ex -sc'%p|q!' /dev/stdin
```

Here is simple example how to print the file after substitution:

```
$ ex /etc/hosts +%s/127/128/ge -sc'%p|q!'
```

More examples for editing files in-place:

```
$ ex +'%s/127/128/g' -cswq file
$ ex -sc '%s/olddomain\.com/newdomain.com/g|x' file
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/olddomain\.com/s//newdomain.com/g' w q | ex -s file
$ ex -s "$file" <<< $'g/old/s//new/g\nw\nq'
$ ex -sc 'argdo %s/old/new/ge|x' ./**
$ find . -type f -exec ex -sc '%s/old/new/g|x' {} \;
```

You can also use `-s {scriptin}` so the commands are loaded from the file, in example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" '%s/foo/test/ge' 'wq' > cmds.vim
$ vim -s cmds.vim -es file
```

or using I/O redirection:

```
$ vim file < cmds.vim
```

To edit one file and save the changes to another, check the following examples:

```
$ ex +%s/127/128/g -sc'wq! new_file' /etc/hosts
$ cat /etc/hosts /etc/fstab | vim - -es '+:%s/foo/test/g' '+:wq! file3'
```

---

#### More practical examples.

[Real live example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes#Ex-mode) from the [RPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) specification:

```
vim -E -s Makefile <<-EOF
   :%substitute/CFLAGS = -g$/CFLAGS =-fPIC -DPIC -g/
   :%substitute/CFLAGS =$/CFLAGS =-fPIC -DPIC/
   :%substitute/ADAFLAGS =$/ADAFLAGS =-fPIC -DPIC/
   :update
   :quit
EOF
```

[Extracting html tags](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6389/21471):

```
ex -s +'bufdo!/<div.*id=.the_div_id/norm nvatdggdG"2p' +'bufdo!%p' -cqa! *.html
```

[Removing XML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30040839/55075):

```
ex -s +'%s/<[^>].\{-}>//ge' +%p +q! file.txt
```

[Removing style tag from the header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33053842/55075) and print the parsed output:

```
curl -s http://example.com/ | ex -s +'/<style.*/norm nvatd' +%p -cq! /dev/stdin
```

[Parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33053678/55075) with multiple complex rules:

```
ex -V1 $PAGE <<-EOF
  " Correcting missing protocol, see: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2359 "
  %s,'//,'http://,ge
  %s,"//,"http://,ge
  " Correcting relative paths, see: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2359 "
  %s,[^,]\zs'/\ze[^>],'http://www.example.com/,ge
  %s,[^,]\zs"/\ze[^>],"http://www.example.com/,ge
  " Remove the margin on the left of the main block. "
  %s/id="doc_container"/id="doc_container" style="min-width:0px;margin-left : 0px;"/g
  %s/<div class="outer_page/<div style="margin: 0px;" class="outer_page/g
  " Remove useless html elements. "
  /<div.*id="global_header"/norm nvatd
  wq " Update changes and quit.
EOF
```

Even more examples:

- [How can I replace a string with another string in a variable, a stream, a file, or in all the files in a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)
- [What is the EX-mode for batch processing for?](https://superuser.com/questions/22455/vim-what-is-the-ex-mode-for-batch-processing-for) at superuser SE

---

See also:

- [Convert tabs to spaces in every file of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29736874/55075) at SO
- [Remove trailing whitespaces from all files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23657918/55075) at SO
- [How to write whole buffer to standard output from the command line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/798/how-to-write-whole-buffer-to-standard-output-from-the-command-line) at Vim SE
- [Is it possible to execute a VIM script in a non-interactive mode?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-vim-script-in-a-non-interactive-mode) at unix SE
- [Pipe Vim buffer to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686183/pipe-vim-buffer-to-stdout) at SO
- [write buffer content to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219479/vim-write-buffer-content-to-stdout) at SO
- [Learning the vi Editor/Vim/Modes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes)
- [How to remove inner content of html tag conditionally?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3299/467)

---

Comment: This is a [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat); simply use `vim '+:0,$s/foo/test/g' '+:wq! file2' file1` instead.

Comment: Note that at least some of these examples aren't POSIX-compliant, for instance, `bufdo`.  Even though Vim is what's installed virtually everywhere, it's worth knowing that you *can* script file editing using only [POSIX-compliant features of `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

Comment: This question & answer is what first inspired me to look into `ex` and really learn it.  Thank you.  Some further reading on this subject (full disclosure: I wrote these ;) is: [reversing every four lines with `ex`](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6289/4676), and [using the `-c` option](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6247/4676).  You might add them to your link list at the bottom, if you want.  :)