# How to write whole buffer to standard output from the command line?

Tags: command-line, invocation, unix, ex-mode

I would like to write whole buffer into standard output (`/dev/stdout`) instead of the file and the following command works as expected while editing the file:

```
:w >> /dev/stdout
```

<sup>Hint: Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to refresh the screen.</sup>

But it doesn't work as expected when I'm trying to do the same from the command line ([non-interactively](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467)), in example:

```
$ echo This is example. | vim - '+:w >> /dev/stdout' '+:q!'
Vim: Reading from stdin...
```

The same with `:w !tee`, `:x! /dev/stdout`, `:%print` and similar.

Before quit, it's saying: `[Device] 1L, 17C appended`.

Is there any way of forcing vim to write the standard input into standard output in the middle of a pipe? Maybe it's somehow buffered?

Comment: Just curious, what are you trying to accomplish? As in, what will vim do for you here that some other tool might not?

Comment: @JayThompson I'm trying to use `vim` for file parsing instead of `sed` (e.g. mass repeated complex changes to multiple large files). The example doesn't do anything to keep it simple and not making potential duplicate of another [post](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467).

Comment: You know about vipe, so any reason you're not using it?

Comment: @muru I didn't use it yet, not much documentation available and it's [off-topic](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/188/467) here.

Comment: Questions about vipe might be, but there's no reason it can't be the answer. So I am wondering why I shouldn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @muru Try answering with `vipe`, sounds interesting. I've found the solution for `vim` already, easier than I thought, I'll post it as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To print buffer to shell standard output, `vim` needs to start in Ex mode, otherwise it'll open "normal" way with its own window and clear any output buffers on quit.

Here is the simplest working example:

```
$ echo foo | vim -e '+%print' '+q!' /dev/stdin
foo
```

or even shorter:

```
$ echo foo | ex +%p -cq! /dev/stdin
$ echo foo | ex +"%p|q!" /dev/stdin
```

<sup>Note: The command `vim -e` is basically equivalent to [`ex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) command.</sup>

Special file descriptor to standard input needs to be specified (`/dev/stdin`) in order to prevent extra annoying messages (as explained below).

---

And here are some examples with parsing strings:

```
$ echo This is example. | vim -e '+s/example/test/g' '+%print' '+q!' /dev/stdin
This is test.
$ echo This is example. | vim - -es '+s/example/test/g' '+%print' '+q!'
Vim: Reading from stdin...
This is test.
```

<sup>Note: The last example shows extra annoying message which is not possible to hide it, it's because a standard strategy of reading the whole file into memory and saying it was read from the standard input. The first example works without the message, because the file produce endless data without an end-of-file ([EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)) signal, so it'll will never reach the end of its input reading.</sup>

---

Related:

- [How to write buffer content to stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219479/how-to-write-buffer-content-to-stdout) at stackoverflow
- [Pipe Vim buffer to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686183/pipe-vim-buffer-to-stdout) at stackoverflow

Comment: You can just do `+q!` rather than `+:q!`, right?

Comment: @AndrewMacFie It's same thing, updated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[`vipe`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/vipe.1) is a convenient tool for editing pipelines, part of the `moreutils` package. It is a wrapper for editors (including the `vi` which gives it its name). It uses the `EDITOR` environment variable to set the editor, so, like with other tools that make use of `EDITOR` (such as `crontab`, `visudo`, etc.), you can script actions using that variable. For example, you can change it to do:

```
$ echo foo | EDITOR='vim +:s/foo/bar/ +wq' vipe | tail
bar
```

Of course, complicated actions might devolve to quoting hell, so you could write a script:

```
#! /bin/sh

vim "+:s/foo/bar" '+wq' "$@"
```

And use `EDITOR="sh /path/to/script"`.