# How do I list my current vim plugins without opening vim?

Tags: plugin-system

For example, if I execute the following command from the terminal:

```
vim -c PluginList
```

this command opens vim and lists my currently installed plugins.  How do I execute the above command but redirect the output to my terminal?

Comment: In my installation of `vim`, there's no `:PluginList` command available. Is that command itself part of a plugin?

Comment: As your listing command writes to a buffer, I think that [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/798/1841) is strongly related if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you appear to be using Vundle, you could simply grep your `vimrc`:

```
$ grep -c Plugin ~/.vimrc
```

Comment: Should have thought of that before.  I use the following command

Comment: grep -ri "Bundle" ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: modified original answer to keep only the finished script version.

For future reference to people browsing this question, here's a solution to the original question that will work even if `Vundle` is not being used with `vim` (longer than @romainl's answer that does require `Vundle`, which seems to be fine for the OP).

The following script assumes a standard unix-like environment with access to common utilities such as `sed`, `sort` and `mktemp`. Just paste into `somefile` in your `$path`, then `chmod +x somefile` and execute `somefile` on the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp=$(mktemp)
vim +"help local-additions" +"sav! $tmp" +"qall"
sed '1,/LOCAL ADDITIONS/d' $tmp | sed '/^$/,$d' | sortj
rm $tmp
```

Here's an example of output when invoking this script from the command-line:

```
|bufkill.txt|  Manage buffer display upon removal of current buffer   
|fugitive.txt|  A Git wrapper so awesome, it should be illegal 
|matchit.txt|   Extended "%" matching
|now.txt|           A pure vim minimalistic personal wiki 
|recover.vim|   Show differences for recovered files
|sneak.txt|  motion improved - Version 1.7.2
|snipMate.txt|  Plugin for using TextMate-style snippets in Vim.
|startify.txt|  The fancy start screen.
|surround.txt|  Plugin for deleting, changing, and adding "surroundings"
|undotree.txt|  Display your undo history in a graph
|vimux.txt|   easily interact with tmux
```

Note that it will miss any plugins that don't have a proper vim help file (in the `.doc/` subdirectory of the plugin).

Comment: I really like that script.  I just which there was a simple command line tool to show the Plugins installed at any given time.