# How to use "-c" command line option?

Tags: ex-command

Fully realizing the heritage of `vi`, I know that its predecessor (`ex`) could be, and was, used for command line processing of files ("sed-style", if you like).

The manpage says:

> `-c` {command}
>
> {command} will be executed after the first file has been read.  {command} is interpreted as an Ex command.  If the {command} contains spaces it must be enclosed in double  quotes  (this depends on the shell that is used).

And:

> `-e`
>
> Start Vim in Ex mode, just like the executable was called "ex".

But I was unable to find "real-life" examples, or get something like a simple search-and-replace to work myself. I like examples...

So let's assume a `file.txt`...

```
abcdef
```

...and I would like to open that file, remove all occurrences of `e` in it (`:%s/e//g` if I were in full `vim` mode), save, and close.

How would I go about it?

Comment: You can also use `+` instead of `-c`, like `+%s/e//g`, see: [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An "ex command" means anything that you type in the commandline after the `:`, such as `:write`, it doesn't really have anything to do with "ex mode", as such. ex mode is a "mode" where you only have the commandline, and not the graphical editor ("vi" stands for "visual ex mode").

So it's really as simple as:

```
vim -c ':%s/e//g' -c ':wq' file.txt
```

There's no need to use "ex mode". You can if you want:

```
vim -e -c ':%s/e//g' -c ':wq' file.txt
```

It has the advantage of not messing with your terminal so much, but other than that there's little difference.

Comment: And at this point I wonder what I did wrong, because I am sure I tried just that. Well, gotta check the command history on the office system tomorrow. :-D Cheers, and thanks!

Comment: I think using `-es` is more performant, I have noticed a small "blink" without it as Vim started up and quit.

Comment: @muru, I don't know if that's performance so much as the fact that `-s` will make `ex` silent.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

The easiest portable way to do this is:

```
printf '%s\n' %s/e//g x | ex file
```

This avoids error conditions discussed below.

---

**Original Answer**

One of the advantages of `ex` as opposed to Vim is that [`ex` is guaranteed by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).

If you're in the sysadmin world and you need to script automated edits to text files (e.g. configuration files to be edited across thousands of different remote servers), you want to use something *portable*.  Perl is great but not portable—and it's overkill for very simple file edits.  `sed` and `awk` are both guaranteed by POSIX, but they're not designed for in-place file editing.  (`sed` has a `-i` switch in some implementations such as GNU `sed` to allow for in-place file editing, but for portable scripting that option shouldn't be relied upon as it is not in the [POSIX standard for `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).)

The correct tool for the job is `ex`.

For your example, removing all instances of the letter "e" from the file, the `ex` command is simple (and portable):

```
ex -sc '%s/e//g | x' file
```

The `-s` switch starts `ex` silently, for batch processing (as opposed to interactive use where messages are printed out to the terminal).

The `-c` switch precedes the command to be run.

The substitute command is as you wrote it.

The vertical bar separates commands to be run sequentially (unless you're [using it with the `g`lobal command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6245/4676), but we're not.)

The `x` command exits after writing any changes to the file.  (It only writes to the file if edits were made, thus preserving the file's timestamp if no edits were necessary.)

---

**There is one *major* caveat to the above command:** If the letter "e" doesn't exist anywhere in the file, the substitute command will fail and the `x` command won't be executed.  This will leave you staring at a silently running `ex` process with no error output, or output of any kind.  It's not at all obvious in this case what's happening, but it's actually waiting for you to type in `ex` commands.  (It's more obvious if you omit the `-s` flag, so that you are actually prompted for input with a colon.)  Just type `q!` to exit in this case.

If I were to actually use this to edit files on remote servers, of course, I would want the command to exit correctly even if there weren't any instances of the letter "e" in the files being edited.  Vim has an `e` flag for the substitute command which would handle this by suppressing `e`rrors if the regex weren't matched:

```
ex -sc '%s/e//ge | x' file
```

But the POSIX way would be to use the `g`lobal command to run the `s`ubstitute command on all lines matching the given regex—and to not run substitute at all if the regex weren't found:

```
ex -sc 'g/e/s///g
x' file
```

Comment: But what if the platform you are using Vim on is *not* POSIX (and therefore doesn't have `ex`)? ;-)  (Just pulling your leg, good answer.)

Comment: Shouldn't the last example be `ex -sc 'g/e/s///g | x' file`?

Comment: @Timm, nope.  [See for yourself](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_13_20)—using `|` in a global command just adds to the command which is executed for every matching line.  So after the first line gets the substitution performed, the `x` command would run, causing the editor to exit.  You can get around this by embedding a newline, or (my preferred method) you can use `printf` to pipe the commands to `ex`.

Comment: @Wildcard, can you show how you use `printf` in this example? Thanks!

Comment: @Timm, I already edited it in at the top of the answer.  ;)