# Why aren't :g/X/d changes saved in Ex?

Tags: global-command, ex-command

I've the following file (which is a simplification of the `hosts` file):

```
126.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
128.0.0.1
```

and I'm trying to invoke the following command:

```
ex +g/127/d -cwq file
```

which is supposed to remove lines consisting `127`, then write and quit.

It works when using `vim -e`, however it doesn't work using `ex`/`vi`.

Although when printing buffer after the change, it seems the change has been made:

```
ex +"g/127/d|%p" file
```

but it also displays the following warning:

> Badly formed address

I'm using original Ex v4.0 (gritter) 3/25/05. On OS X can be installed via `brew install ex-vi`.

Why doesn't the above command work in `ex` editor? And how do I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems here. First ex is made for interactive use. You can't use several -c commands. Second, and this is a specialty of the :g command, you can't separate several commands using the '|'. A `:g/127/d|wq` command would write and quit after the first match)
This makes it effectively useless to add another command after the -c command. What works however is this traditional approach

```
cat <<EOF|ex /foobar
g/127/d
x
EOF
```

This also works with nvi. Though, I could make nvi also use

```
nvi -e +'g/127/d|
wq' foobar
```

but that is also not portable. (I don't know, why this works, however).

Comment: Perl could be used as an alternative to avoid interactive mode: `$ perl -i -ne 'print unless /127/;' file` - it has the advantage of being installed on most systems by default.

Comment: or use sed, which should be also available on each POSIX system

Comment: You *can* use several `-c` commands in *some* implementations (not required by [POSIX specifications for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html)), but I believe in all such implementations you must use `-s` to set `ex` to "silent mode, in preparation for batch processing."

Comment: For a one-liner, you can use `printf` instead of `cat`: `printf '%s\n' g/127/d x | ex /foobar`

Answer (score 1):

If it works with the Vim Ex mode but fails with [Ex v4.0 (gritter)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ex-vi/) them it is probably an issue with the latter application. I would suggest reporting on the project bug tracker, but it seems that it isn't supported anymore.

If the command works with `vim -e`, wouldn't it be better to just stick with it?

Comment: POSIX doesn't allow several -c commands, also I believe the ex-vi project is dead

Answer (score 1):

For full [POSIX compatibility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) (i.e. portability), try:

```
ex -sc 'g/^127/d
x' file
```

I improved your regex slightly because it appeared to me that your intent was to only delete lines *beginning* with "127"; if that was incorrect, remove the `^` carat.

The `-s` command causes `ex` to run silently.

The `g`lobal command must be terminated by a newline.

`+cmd` is not guaranteed by POSIX; only `-c cmd` is guaranteed, and multiple `-c` flags are not necessarily supported.

`x` is the "exit" command; it saves changes and exits, but only writes to the file if changes were actually made.  (So if no changes were made, the timestamp on the file will be unaffected—which is preferable in many situations.)