# Using -c command line option for Vim 7.4 on Windows produces errors

Tags: command-line, global-command

The following commands work fine when I issue them from the command mode in Vim:

```
:%s/\(^\s\+\)\(\S\+.*)\s*\){$/\1\2\r\1{/g
:g/^\s*\/\/$/d
```

But when I run the above commands as a script as below:

> vim -c "commands.vim" myfile.c

I get errors:

[image]

Note: I am aware of this question: [How to use "-c" command line option?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5273/how-to-use-c-command-line-option) but it has not helped with the error.

Comment: `-c` expects a Vim command. Merely mentioning a vimscript is not a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim's `-s {scriptin}` command line argument<sup>*</sup> allows you to supply a file the contents of which will be interpreted as if you had typed them in, character by character.

This can be used for normal mode commands, but because you also generally enter command-line mode commands by typing them in, it works fine for ex commands too, so long as you include the colons at the start of each line (as you have).

```
vim -s commands.vim myfile.c
```

See `:help -s` for more details.

<sub>* Not to be confused with Vim's *other* `-s` argument, which only applies when ex mode is also specified: see `:help -s-ex`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment from ChristianBraband, I found a solution, with help from this page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes

Modify the `commands.vim` script so that file update and quit are included at the end:

```
:%s/\(^\s\+\)\(\S\+.*)\s*\){$/\1\2\r\1{/g
:g/^\s*\/\/$/d
:update
:quit
```

Run from the command line as follows:

> vim -c "source commands.vim" myfile.c

Update: Removed the unnecessary -E option per comment from @Rich.

Comment: `vim -s commands.vim myfile.c` is a bit simpler. See `:h -s` (and note difference from `:h -s-ex`).

Comment: @Rich Yes, this works and it is what I was after originally.  If you can post it as an answer, I'll accept. Thank you.

Comment: @Rich By the way, what a poor command-line design, having -s-ex and -s!

Comment: I concur! Note that with your solution you don't need the colons at the start of each line (although it works fine with them).

Comment: @Rich Yet colons are required for -s (scriptin)! Another inconsistency.  When I tried -s (scriptin) without colons, the whole thing exploded and the script itself got inserted into the file.

Comment: That's because the two solutions work in different ways. Yours, using "source" via a `-c` parameter, is running ex commands. `-s` is emulating you actually typing the commands in.

Comment: Note also that the `-E` in your command is unnecessary. The commands in your file are run as Vimscript by your `source` command, so there's no reason to use ex-mode.

Comment: @Rich Thank you, this exchange has really been invaluable.