# Where are my recent commands stored in Vim?

Tags: command-history, viminfo

So I have made about 10/12 substitutions in my current file using `%s/longpatternN//g`. Unfortunately I have to apply these same substitutions in 10 
 or more of my files. I can access my last commands via `up arrow`. So I am trying to copy my last command pattern, build a `sed` command and put them in a shell script to automate this boring stuff. But it looks like my Git Bash not letting me select and copy these substitution command texts via my mouse in vim. So where can I access all history of my all recent vim commands? Can we access any files may be vim storing these commands into?

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't bother writing a shell script that calls sed. You can just copy/write the commands directly into a `commands.vim` file and then run it on a file with [vim -s commands.vim file.txt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/14325/343). Or [put them in a function](http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/advanced/#globals-commands-functions) that you can call from within Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. I thing Vim inside Git Bash can access the windows clipboard, so you can try the following:
`q:` to enter to history 'edit' mode, then `k` many times as needed or search for your pattern with `?`, and then

`0v$
"+y`

Here `+` is the register for the clipboard. After the previos commands you can paste on the bash prompt without problem

And the other option is (on command prompt): `cat $HOME/.viminfo | grep ':s'`

Since `$HOME/.viminfo` contains information about your vim sessions, including commands.

But I also recommend to take a look on `:h :bufdo` and `:h :argdo`

Comment: I Just saw it would suffice with `grep '%s' $HOME/.viminfo`

Comment: Worth noting :& and & as well, i think