# argdo command hanging

Tags: ex-command

I am interested in editing multiple files. Using this answer:

[How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/#789)

I came up with my own test case:

```
seq 10 14 | tee pa.txt > qu.txt
ex -sc 'argdo %s/1/Z/ge|x' *.txt
```

However when I run the Ex command, the terminal just hangs, it does not complete
the command. If I remove the `-s`, the command still hangs with this output:

```
"pa.txt" 5 lines, 15 characters
Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:
```

Comment: It does not on my machine using zsh, can you add your configuration?

Comment: First remove the `-s` of your second command, if you are trying to debug something the silent mode isn't helping. Then `man ex` says that you need to put double quote around your command if it contains spaces so you should also change that. Once it is done you can give us what vim says and it will probably be easier to help you :-)

Comment: I second Nobe4. The command works fine, if `ex` is actually Vim. If it is actually `ex` (say, from [ex-vi](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net)), I get an error about `argdo` and `ex` waits around for me to enter commands.

Comment: Hmm, that looks like Vim. What does `ex --version` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[muru’s comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7343#comment12060_7343) lead me to the answer. According to [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#argument-list), `argdo`
requires the `listcmds` feature at compile time. It appears I do not have it:

```
$ ex --version | grep -e Features -e listcmds
Small version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-cursorshape     -listcmds        -reltime         +windows
```

Here is a workaround:

```
for b in *.txt
do
  ex -sc '%s/1/Z/|x' "$b"
done
```

Comment: That explains your recent post on [ubuntu.se]. I wondered why it didn't use `bufdo` or `argdo`.

Comment: @muru also because argdo is not POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html, nor is `{1..4}`