# How can you use vim as a stream editor?

Tags: vimscript, bash

Like most programmers, I perform a lot of repetitive tasks. In optimising my workflow, I'm taking some of those repetitive tasks, and refactoring them into shell scripts.

One thing that I'm trying to automate is the recreation of PostgreSQL views. I have the following view.

```
create or replace view person as
select
    1 as person_id
    , 'John'::text as first_name,
    'Doe'::text as last_name;
```

I can dump this view with `psql -c "\\d+ person"` and the output is as follows:

```
                   View "public.person"
   Column   |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------
 person_id  | integer |           | plain    | 
 first_name | text    |           | extended | 
 last_name  | text    |           | extended | 
View definition:
 SELECT 1 AS person_id,
    'John'::text AS first_name,
    'Doe'::text AS last_name;
```

I can reformat this text into a `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statement with the following keystrokes in vim: `gg0df"iCREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <ESC>$cl AS<ESC>j0d/^View definition:<CR>ddG$:wq` (I've reformatted `<ESC>`, etc, in the above).

I've got the above working perfectly, except for the screen "flashes" that occur. For example, if at the shell I type `a=$(psql -c "\\d+ person" | vim -s <vimscriptfile> -); echo "$a"` then my screen "flashes" before outputting the nicely format SQL.

Is there any way to remove this flash? Or is there a better *using-vim-in-a-pipeline* approach than what I'm employing?

Comment: What is `pg-recreate-view`? If it is using Vim somehow, you might want to use the `-Nes` options with it.

Comment: Just a wrapper function around the `psql` call.

Comment: Um, this is possible a stupid question, but you don't seem to be using Vim in your example shell command?

Comment: @Rich "I can reformat this text into a `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` statement with the following keystrokes in **vim**:" - First sentence right after the second big preformatted block.

Comment: But that's not using Vim as a stream editor... that's typing commands into Vim manually. So is the problem simply that you don't know how to use Vim as a stream editor? If so, what do you mean by "I've got the above working perfectly, except for the screen "flashes" that occur."?

Comment: What I don't understand is, does [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-to-edit-files-non-interactively-e-g-in-pipeline) answer your question, or is your question actually about a problem with the method described in there?

Comment: @Rich, I believe I am doing what your referenced question does, but vim still takes over my terminal for about 1/10th of a second, and when wrapping it in shell substitution (e.g., `a=$(psql ... | vim -s ... -)`) then echoing that value causes the screen to flash. I think I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Your edit makes things a lot clearer! Unfortunately, it also means I'm unable to help you. :(

Comment: Perhaps a Neovim expert could help here; sounds like something a headless instance could be used for.  https://neovim.io/community/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the correct answer is 'use sed instead'. However, maybe [vipe](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vipe) might be of use?

Comment: Vim has a stream-editing mode, called `ex` mode. It is possible to start vim in `ex` mode, and it is possible to switch to it after opening a file (`:ex`). (`:vi` will switch back to visual mode). I've never used ex mode, but it might be what you're looking for. Maybe replacing `vim` in your command with `ex` would be enough?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid screen flashes when editing stream [non-interactively](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467), you need to start Vim in Ex mode by adding `-e` (*Ex mode*) or `-E` (*improved Ex mode*) into your command-line arguments.

Here is the simple example editing text from the standard output and printing the result into standard output:

```
$ echo "foo bar" | vim -E +%s/foo.// +%p -cq! /dev/stdin
bar
```

To parse your output, you may try the following syntax:

```
$ psql -c "\\d+ person" | \
  ex +'1s/\s\+View "\([^"]\+\)"/CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW \1 AS/g' +'2,/View.definition/d' +%j +%p -scq! /dev/stdin
```

The output should look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.person AS SELECT 1 AS person_id, 'John'::text AS first_name, 'Doe'::text AS last_name;
```

Explanation:

- Using `ex` command is equivalent to run Vim in Ex mode (`vim -e`).
- `+'cmd'`/`-c {cmd}` - Invokes Ex command.
- `-cq!` - Forcibly **q**uit Vim as we're not saving any files.
- `-s` - Run in **s**ilent mode (prevents extra screen flashes).
- `/dev/stdin` - We use `/dev/stdin` as an input file, because [using `-` doesn't work properly](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2342).
- `1s/pattern/something/g` - Substitute `pattern` with `something` in the **1**st line.
- `2,/pattern/d` - **D**elete content starting from the **2**nd line to the line with `pattern`.
- `%j` - **J**oins all the lines together.
- `%p` - **P**rints the buffer to the console output.

Comment: The following package should also help you do this without the extra flags: https://github.com/MilesCranmer/vim-stream

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your macro but here is a (far from ideal) approach to your problem: Register persistently your steps in a macro and then launch Vim and tell it to directly execute your macro and close again.

Ex:
In your `.vimrc`, you register the macro:

```
" convert everything to uppercase
let @x = 'ggVGU'
```

Start Vim, call the macro from the cmd line and close Vim again:

```
$ cat test.txt
sdfas;dlfasdf
asdf
adf

$ vim -c ":norm! @x" -c ":x" test.txt

$ cat test.txt
SDFAS;DLFASDF
ASDF
ADF
```

This will obviously start vim and close it right a way. I guess there are some optimizations possible. Make a shell `alias` for the whole thing, start Vim without plugins/vimrc and only load your dummy vimrc (to make startup fast if that's a problem), probably other ideas as well.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2024537/2923406) explains how to record macros and add them to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: Incidentally, you can yank text into a macro register (e.g. `"ay` to yank a macro into `a`), and then run it (`@a`). You just have to be careful not to yank the newline character at the end, which `yy` does.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is asking how to use Vim as a stream editor. How would you use your solution in a pipeline, and how does it improve on the existing solution the question-asker describes?