# Attempt to create a buffer output script

Tags: linux

I'm in a Linux class right now and the question was brought up as to if there was a command to see what's in your buffer list inside vi. I searched online to see if I could find anything, but found nothing, so I went ahead and started to attempt creating a script myself, however I cannot seem to get the commands right.

Here's what I have so far:

```
while [ : ]
do
clear

echo "What buffer position would you like to see?"

read choice

case $choice in
1) '"1p' ;;
2) '"2p' ;;
3) '"3p' ;;
4) '"4p' ;;
5) '"5p' ;;
6) '"6p' ;;
7) '"7p' ;;
8) '"8p' ;;
9) '"9p' ;;
0) '"0p' ;;


esac ; read -n 1 ;

done
```

I've tried swapping the command for something like this too:

```
1) vi -c \"1p ;;
```

Any ideas on how I might be able to pull a vi command out into command line like that? Thank you! (Side note, this is NOT homework or required. I just want to see if it can be done. I asked my professor to help me with it, and even he was stumped)

Comment: Er, `:ls` lists buffers. Were you perhaps talking about registers? In that case, its `:reg [r]`

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble Judging by the code included, I gather that the OP is trying to write a shell script that, *from outside of Vim* outputs the contents of Vim's registers.

Answer (score 2):

First thing's first: I infer from your code (which uses `"1p` etc.) that you actually mean "register" when you write "buffer". In Vim terminology, a "buffer" is Vim's in-memory representation of a file (which may or may not actually exist on disk).

Secondly, I gather from your code that what you are trying to achieve is the construction of a bash script that will allow you to query the contents of Vim's registers *from outside of Vim.*

That said, here is a command that will print the contents of Vim's numbered register `"0` (the yank register) from your shell:

```
vim -es -c'normal "0P' -c%p -cq! -
```

I leave it as an exercise to you to figure out how to incorporate that into your bash script: it's outside the scope of this site.

Broken down:

- `vim`: Run Vim,
- `-es`: in silent mode,
- `-c`: passing in the commands...
- `normal "0P`: use the normal mode command `"0P` to paste the contents of the `"0` register at the start of the buffer,
- `-c%p`: print the contents of the buffer (i.e. output it to `stdout` i.e. the shell)
- `-cq!`: quit, discarding the contents of the buffer (which you altered with the `"0P` command),

See `:help vim-arguments`, [this earlier question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-to-edit-files-non-interactively-e-g-in-pipeline), and [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11373/how-can-you-use-vim-as-a-stream-editor) for more details on how this works.