# How open two files but one came from stdout

Tags: multiple-files

all these works

```
git show bf5500a8 | vim -R - 

vim file1 file2 -O 

git show bf5500a8 > tmpfile ; vim tmpfile  file2 -O ; rm tmpfile
```

but I'd like to know if I can open stdout and other file directly , without create a tmp file ?

UPDATE 2021.03.15 :
What I really like to know is how vim can replace "-" and use pipe stdout as input. To, for example, open two files in split mode but one came from stdout , Note I'd like use -O option (vertical split mode) and stdout be on left side ...

Thank you

Comment: almost , how I can apply  short options like -O ?

Comment: vim -O /path/to/file  /path/to/file2

Comment: ah , ok , as  -c prevents the use of "flags" , the answer almost do what I'd like to have ...

Comment: Hi, please don't delete your answer , it better than nothing , I don't write well English

Comment: I changed my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`-c`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#-c) which allows you to specify an Ex command to be run after the first file is loaded...

```
git show bf5500a8 | vim -c 'e /path/to/file' -
```

You want them in a split?

```
git show bf5500a8 | vim -c 'split /path/to/file' -
```

**Update:** Since you insist on using the `-O` flag I can show you a trick *sort of* works from *Bash-like shells only* but Vim is not intended to be used this way and you may get funky results....

```
git show bf5500a8 | vim -O /dev/stdin /path/to/file
```

Note the warning you get.

When you exit and your shell seems unresponsive you can type `reset`.

Like I said, this is not how Vim is meant to work. If you want to do stream editing you can use Ex mode [How can you use vim as a stream editor?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11373/how-can-you-use-vim-as-a-stream-editor?noredirect=1&lq=1) ... but you're not going to get a clean result using -O without hacks. You might also look at `vipe` or `vim-stream`.

Also, you added the `-O` requirement after I originally posted a fully working solution to your original question so all of this is really above and beyond the call of duty.

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```
vim <(git show bf5500a8) /path/to/file -O
```

based on solution to compare two commits https://stackoverflow.com/a/23527631/778517

Comment: FYI that's called Process Substitution. I lumped that under the category of "hacks" due to 1) it only works with certain shells like Bash 2) it's system dependent (OS must support "named pipes" or similar) and 3) the potential for similar problems to other, related solutions...but if it's working well for you I'm glad to hear it.